# Sorting a Doubly Linked List Alphabetically

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have an assignment where I am supposed to read names and weights from a text file, and construct a doubly linked list out of the information. One pointer of the DLL should keep track of the sorted weights, and the other should keep track of the sorted names. Ive implemented a function that reads in the names from a text file, and created a doubly linked list in sorted order based on weights. However, Im not trying to fix the pointers/links that keep track of the alphabetized list, and Im running into a lot of problems.

```
    struct Node{
std::string name;
int weight;
Node* NextName;
Node* NextWeight;

Node(std::string newName, int newWeight){
    this -> name = newName;
    this -> weight = newWeight;
    this -> NextName = nullptr;
    this -> NextWeight = nullptr;
}
};

class DoublyLinkedList{
private:
Node* head;

public:
void sortByName(){
    setUpLinks();

    std::cout << "\n Sorted by name: " << std::endl;
    Node* tempHead = head;
    Node* current = head;
    Node* temp = head -> NextWeight;
    Node* prev = head;

    while(temp != nullptr){
        if(temp -> name < tempHead -> name){
            temp -> NextName = tempHead;
            tempHead = temp;
            temp = temp -> NextWeight;
        }

        else{
            while(current -> name < temp -> name){
                prev = current;
                current = current -> NextWeight;
            }
            if(current -> name > temp -> name){
                prev ->NextName = temp;
                temp -> NextName = current;
        }
    }
    temp = temp -> NextWeight;
    current = tempHead;
    }
}

void printByName(){
    Node* tempHead = head;
    while(tempHead != nullptr){
        std::cout << tempHead -> name << ", " << tempHead -> weight << "\n";
        tempHead = tempHead -> NextName;
    }
}

void printByWeight(){
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != nullptr){
        std::cout << temp -> weight << ", " << temp -> name << "\n";
        temp = temp -> NextWeight;
    }
}

void insert(std::string name, int weight){
    Node* temp = head;
    Node* prev = head;

    //Deals with the case of no nodes in the DLL yet
    if(head == nullptr){
        head = new Node(name, weight);
        temp = prev = head;
    }

    //Deals with case that new node is less than only node
    else if(weight < head -> weight){
        Node* newNode = new Node(name, weight);
        newNode -> NextWeight = head -> NextWeight;
        head = newNode;
        if(head -> name > head -> NextWeight -> name){
            head -> NextName = head -> NextWeight;
        }
    }

    //Find iteration
    while (temp -> weight <= weight){
        prev = temp;

        if(temp -> NextWeight == nullptr){
            Node* newNode = new Node(name, weight);
            temp -> NextWeight = newNode;
            return;
        }

        else temp = temp -> NextWeight;
    }

    Node* newNode = new Node(name, weight);
    newNode -> NextWeight = temp;
    prev -> NextWeight = newNode;


}

void setUpLinks(){
    Node* temp = head;
    Node* prev = head;
    while(temp != nullptr){
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp -> NextWeight;
        prev -> NextName = temp;
    }
}

};
int main(){
std::string name = "";
std::string firstName = "";
int weight = 0;
int iteration = 0;

DoublyLinkedList list;

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("Names.txt");
if (!inFile) {
    std::cout << "Couldn't open file";
    exit(1);   // call system to stop
}
while (inFile >> name) {

    inFile >> weight;
    std::cout << "\nIteration " << iteration << ": \n";
    list.insert(name, weight);
    list.printByWeight();
    iteration ++;
}

list.sortByName();
list.printByName();
//list.printByName();
return 0;
}
```

However, it looks like im not getting the correct sorted list in alphabetical order. Not sure what the problem is. To me, it looks like this code should work to sort alphabetically. Any help is greatly appreciated, this is my sample output...

```
Iteration 14: 
99, Annabelle
124, Claire
145, Kevin
150, Jim
150, Brian
156, Bob
164, Steven
174, Michael
175, Chris
182, Jason
199, Abe
200, Richard
212, Tom

Sorted by name: 
Annabelle, 99
Chris, 175
Claire, 124
Jason, 182
Kevin, 145
Jim, 150
```

Comment: Create first a function that swaps two elements in the list. Once this is done, implement your sorting function with it. Don't do both at the same time.

Comment: Depending on your needs, an *in-order-insertion* is almost always preferable to sorting a completed list. Though if you need to sort on different elements you are left with a sorting issue.